# adding menubar to wxpython.grid Table

Tags: python

How one can add a menubar to a wx.grid frame?
I have searched a lot and cannot find any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add it to the grid, you add the grid and a menu bar to a frame, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import wx
import wx.grid

class GridAndMenuFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, 
                          wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(200, 150))

        mbar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu = wx.Menu()
        menu.Append(101, 'E&xit', 'Exit')
        mbar.Append(menu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(mbar)

        grid = wx.grid.Grid(self, -1)
        # obviously, size and configure the grid here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    win = GridAndMenuFrame(None, -1, "grid and menu")
    win.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```